# Ways to lessen or prevent episodes of sleep walking

Tags: medications, sleep, treatment-options, sleep-walking

I am currently on medication to dampen my sleep walking. The medication is amitriptilyne, but lately it seems to be having no effect.

For the past few weeks I have been getting up at around 3am for a nightly sleepwalk in which I go to the fridge, get food, and take it back to my bed.

I don't usually eat it, but it is getting ruined being out of the fridge.

Are there any methods or other effective medication to help prevent sleep walking? I'm ruining quite a bit of food.

When sleepwalking I seem to have full cognitive ability so locks and other mechanisms don't work.

Comment: On a more serious note, how easily are you awakened while sleep walking? (Alarms, arm squeeze, etc.)

Comment: I'm awoken if someone speaks to me, but grabbing me isn't a good idea. Also, I'm quite a big lad, so being fastened to the bed would just mean it came with me.

Comment: @Terry Have you tried locking down your fridge over night or install the alarm once opened. In my opinion, your issue is mind issue, so you need to work on it inside your head. You won't find any fixed answer here.

Comment: @Terry Have you tried Melatonin? It could change your sleeping behavior.

Comment: @Terry Did **Prince** answer your question or are you still looking for an answer? The question keeps on bouncing to the top if no answer is accepted. You could update what your looking for or if anything has changed... Prince answer seems pretty solid to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known way to absolutely prevent sleepwalking; however, certain steps can be taken to minimize one's risk. These include:

- Get adequate sleep.
- Limit stress. Meditate or do relaxation exercises.
- Avoid any kind of stimulation (auditory or visual) prior to bedtime.

http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/how-is-sleepwalking-treated#1